# How to make a window partially clickthrough?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm attempting to create a window with the following properties:

- Completely invisible except for a small, moving region
- Can be clicked through to windows below it, EXCEPT if you click in that small region
- Doesn't show up on the taskbar (although this one isn't as pressing at the moment)

I can figure out how to make the WHOLE window transparent (partially or entirely) and click-through using `WS_EX_LAYERED` and `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT`, setting `TopMost`, and changing the opacity, but I can't figure out how to make these requirements true for the window EXCEPT for a limited part. Any idea where to start?

EDIT: It's been pointed out to me that making a huge, invisible window is rather pointless, and it would be smarter to create a *small* window and use `FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow` and `ShowInTaskbar` to make it borderless and not present on the task bar, then move it around. I still need to figure out how to make the "background" of the window transparent and click-through, so I'm leaving this question up.

Comment: You need to handle `WM_NCHITTEST`

Comment: Please explain why do you want a big invisible click-thru window. It seems that you want to rape the basic concept of Windows UI. Instead, you can achive what you want with a small fully visible Window which you will dynamically move.

Comment: @AlKepp I've had to do similar work.  I once developed titles that scrolled on screen, while using other apps, in WinForms.  You want to click through the region that's not text.  I understand the question to understand it; so that you can help better solve the problem, but 'rape the basic concept of Windows UI'?  That's a bit bold. Windows UI is built on a common interface but meant to be customizable at it's roots.

Answer (score 0):

So, I managed to figure it out through trial and error, and I apologize for taking people's time.

The solution here is to:

- Override `OnPaintBackground` to be an empty method, so nothing actually gets painted on the back
- Set the style so it supports Transparent as a back color, then set the back color and `TransparencyKey` to Transparent
- Set `FormBorderStyle` to None, `TopMost` to True, `ControlBox` to False, `ShowInTaskbar` to False, and `Text` to `String.Empty`

End result: A form that is completely invisible and that can be clicked through, while still letting the user interact with any controls placed on the form.

Comment: You're on the right track here.  You can actually paint the path of the Window however you want; masking it to only be clickable where it's visible.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII Can you give me a bit more detail on this, please? What do you mean by "masking it to only be clickable where it's visible," in particular? This sounds like exactly what I want to do, but I have never heard of the concept.

Comment: It's been a long time since I've done WinForms; because everything you're wanting to do is accomplished so much easier and performs better with WPF and XAML (hint if you can switch you'll love it) but I have written applications that do this masking many apps.  I'll have to pull up those old projects to give you details on how but you're on the right track with overriding the pain, using transparency key, etc.

Comment: I made one app where the Window was a specific shape and only that portion was clickable / draggable.  Another where it presented information on the screen above other apps via text and transitions off screen animated (not clickable), and I injected a trial banner into an app that scrolled on the screen above other apps, but you could see through it to be non-obtrusive as possible, and that clicking opened the trial information ETC. Anything is possible... What would you like to accomplish?  I may be able to provide exact code if I find the time.

Comment: Short version: Imagine a drawing of a stick figure that sits in the corner of the screen. My goal is to let the user interact with the stick figure by mousing over it, but NOT by mousing over (for example) the space between the stick figure's arm and body. Any mouse movements that don't intersect the stick figure should just be passed down to windows below the figure. I'm planning on making a custom control to take an image and carefully let the user only interact with said image, not the square around it, but I don't know how yet.

Comment: Exactly and it can be done.  You're on the right track.  One way is to get a jpg (not png) of the image you want. Then make the Window the size of the image, whatever you want to click through on the image give it the same color as the  transparency key of the Window. Use the paint method to draw the image onto the form and nothing else.  If you're image is a stick man you'll see just the stick man and be able to click through the rest.

Comment: You don't have to use an image, you can actually draw the font as any string you want or draw a path from another file or programmatically.